# Can Windows 10's desktop slideshow use pictures from inside multiple subfolders?

Tags: windows-10, themes, slideshow

It seems that Windows 10's desktop slideshow does not use pictures from inside subfolders. Is there a way to get it to use these pictures?

---

I have a *Wallpapers* folder with subfolders like *Landscapes* and *Architecture*. The subfolders have pictures in them. *Wallpapers* has no pictures in it directly.
I want the slideshow to use all of the pictures from all of the subfolders.

In Settings > Personalization > Background, I set:

- Background = *Slideshow*
- Choose albums for your slideshow = *Wallpapers*

The desktop just shows whatever the last photo was, or sometimes just a weird, small grid pattern.

---

If I put a couple pictures in the *Wallpapers* folder, it will use those as expected. So I think the issue is that it doesn't look in subfolders, but I don't want to dismantle my organizational system.
Is there a way to get it to use the pictures from all the subfolders?

Comment: I just tried putting all the subfolders in a library, but the settings won't let me point the slideshow at a library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wanted to do this exact same thing and it took me a while to figure out how to accomplish it. What I ended up doing was using a combination of a custom library and the old Windows wallpaper settings.

To create a library with the folders you want, click on Libraries in the left side panel of a Windows folder (or if you removed the Libraries link from there you can just type Libraries into the navigation bar). Once you're in the Libraries folder you can right-click and select new Library. Then add folders to your new library by right-clicking on it, selecting Properties, and clicking the "Add..." button.

The Window 10 "Personalize" window doesn't let you select a library (other than your default Pictures library), but the old-style wallpaper settings does and that can be accessed with this command:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,,@desktop
```

I created a shortcut to this and put it in my Wallpapers folder, but you can also just enter that command in the Cortana search field. From this window you can browse to your new library.

[image]

Comment: That is convoluted, but it does work. I ended up just using [John's Background Switcher](https://johnsad.ventures/software/backgroundswitcher/).

Comment: A somewhat simpler command, `control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper`, was suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3f60fm/windows_10_has_desktop_background_slideshow_lost/)

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate as Microsoft has removed the Windows 7 Desktop Personalization CP from Windows 10 as of the Creators Update spring 2017.

Comment: Yep, this method no longer works after that update. Looks like an external program like John's Background Switcher is the way to do it now.

Comment: @superjos As of now, that just takes me to the regular, Win10 Background tab.

Comment: `C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper`

Comment: [Windows 10 Desktop Background Slideshow Not Seeing Subfolders](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-desktop-background-slideshow-not-seeing-subfolders-library/)

Comment: As this was right, but no longer works, should I un-accept it?

Comment: This seems to work still, on 2004:
`shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper`
(from answers by @superjos & @jeffreygeorge)

Answer (score 4):

As of today, on Windows 10 Version 10.0.15063, this command works:

`C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper`

HTH

Comment: and what does this command do?

Comment: it opens "classic" *Settings\Personalization\Desktop Background* panel

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it in Win 10 by following the steps in this blog
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-desktop-background-slideshow-not-seeing-subfolders-library/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use this script [link_Nto1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/link_Nto1), that I wrote for myself. It will create links to files from multiple folders inside a specified folder and will allow you to quickly switch between different sets of folders.

**Usage example:**

Open PowerShell and install the script:

```
PS> Install-Script -Name link_Nto1
```

Go inside your pictures directory.

```
cd C:/Pictures
```

Run the script:

```
PS> link_Nto1.ps1 desktop_slideshow Landscapes,Aerial,Underwater
```

*The first argument is the configured Windows Desktop Slideshow directory (in this case "desktop_slideshow"), the second argument is a comma separated list of all directories that you want to include in your desktop slideshow ("Landscapes", "Aerial" and "Underwater").*

If you want to switch to a different set of folders, just run the script again with a different list of source folders:

```
PS> link_Nto1.ps1 desktop_slideshow Landscapes,Aerial
```

This will effectively remove folder *"Underwater"* from the slideshow.

Answer (score -3):

Under 'Choose albums for your slideshow', there is a 'Browse' button. It allows you to select a sub-folder (or *any* other folder *anywhere* on your disks):[image: Browse Button]

I have been using that for months successfully.

Comment: I want it to use all the pictures from inside all the subfolders. There does not seem to be any way to select multiple folders, if that's what you meant.

Comment: This didn't work. Windows look inside only one folder, if you choose a folder that hasn't pictures, it will search inside subfolder, but it will stop searching at first folder that it has found pictures and will show only these pictures.